# Geometry nodes, select faces that are connected to the selected edges

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have **these edges**, and I need to **separate the faces** that are connected to these edges.
I think it's possible by using "**evaluate on domain node**", but I couldn't make it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean edge won't interpolate into faces by spilling onto faces that have just one *true* edge. Capture the boolean *true* as float $1$, this will spill to a face depending on the number of edges of that face: $1 \over 3$ for triangles, $0.25$ for quads, $1 \over n$ for $n$-gons ($s \over n$ for all faces, where $s$ is the number of selected edges). Since for any face if at least one edge is selected, the resulting interpolation will be non-zero, it converts back to boolean as *true*.

[image]

[image]